# Background image cutoff on macs

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a mockup website www.hush.technology
and on my windows (17 inch) computer the website background is full screen
but on my mac (13 inch ) the width of the picture is cut off on the right. I generally like to solve problems on my own but I can't figure it out.
my `css` looks like this

```
// CSS CODE
.bgimage { 
    background: url(image url);
    background-size: cover;
    width: auto;
    height: 720px;
}
```

Would anyone know why this is happening. I would love an explanation.

Comment: check my answer... just add position fixed within your class... let me know if you still facing any issues...

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

background-size:cover

Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

I assume the aspect ratio is off, and it is clipping part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to build on what both of these answers have said. But I'll tell you in short: there is no solution to what you're trying to achieve because it isn't possible. Here's why:

[image: Glorious Explanation]

The first box from the left shows what you have as a full screen browser - your image background perfectly covers the screen as you want it to. **Your screen is the same size as the background** and the image ratio is kept.

The box in the middle shows what happens when you resize your browser (or view on your 13" mac, which I'm assuming is a lower resolution). The image gets cut off the left and right! But why? Because the image is doing what it's been told to: keep it's ratio and cover the entire screen. They both have to be met, and the background image doesn't care whether all of itself isn't visible - it just cares that the screen is being covered and the ratio is the same.

The final box (one on the right), is the implementation of user3739658's answer. You've told the image you want it to make itself entirely visible, and keep the ratio. The consequence: it can't cover the whole screen anymore.

Your background image can only be guaranteed to do two of the three at any given time.

- Cover the screen
- Keep the ratio
- Show the entire image

Another panel I could show is the image being told to: cover the screen and show the entire image, which would result in the image being stretched one way or the other.

### The Solution

The easiest thing to do is to remove your static `height: 720px;`, which means the div can now resize based on the width of the browser (to keep the ratio of the background image).

An alternative is to change your background's purpose - your image is mostly made up of three things:

- The actual picture on the right
- Some largish text on the top left
- Lots of background colour

You can split the background up into just having a picture on the right, and text on the left, with your `background` now being just a colour. The advantage of this is that the image will **always** show at the right of the screen, and your text will always show (and is now no longer a picture). Both the text and picture will also never skew, since the property being resized is the `background color`'s width: which doesn't matter since its just a colour fill.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link;

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

good luck!

Comment: This will still cut off the sides of the image

Comment: please double check if it has some container has some fixed width/margin/padding etc. it would be great if you share the link so i can see it live...